# How to pull the output of another webpage into a PHP script

Tags: php, constants

Just like PHP `include` how do I pull the output (not the markup) of a page into another page's php script.

https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/

This link outputs PHP defined constants. I want to include this output in another PHP page to use these constants in that PHP script.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Try to rephrase it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other solution,

```
$homepage = file_get_contents('https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/');
ereg("'(.*)', {1,}'(.*)'", $homepage, $regs);
```

Loop on the array `$regs` to get your constants.

You can see the regex in action [here](https://regex101.com/r/lL5aA7/1)

Answer (score 0):

You can use PHP [simpleHtmlDom](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/)
than you can parse your link  https://api.wordpress.org/secret-key/1.1/salt/ and use a regex to get the constants

Comment: The linked resource isn't a HTML page but plain text, so I don't think looking at the DOM makes sense here.